# how to wait for user to click then console log variable

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, onclick

So right now I am having some trouble with the async/await functions and my goal is to update a variable when the user clicks a button. After this is done then I console log the updated variable. For example in my code I create a global variable called result and then I have a function with an event listener to change the value of the variable when the button is clicked but when I console log the variable I get an undefined variable and not the value I set it to.
Here is the code:
JS file

```
let onlyBtn = document.getElementById("onlyButton");


let result;

async function realMain(){

   await step();
   console.log(result);

}

async function step(){
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
        onlyBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
            result = "nice";
            
        });
        resolve();
    });
    
        
}

realMain();
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <button id="onlyButton">Run</button>
    </div>
    


    <script src="app.js">
        
    </script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make it so I have to wait for the function where the update is done, then I console log the updated variable?

Comment: `nodeResult` is not declared. It is `result`.

Comment: That was just a typo. I still get an undefined when console logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is not triggering event by clicking, and you should pass argument result in resolve

```js
let onlyBtn = document.getElementById("onlyButton");

let result;

async function realMain() {
    await step().then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}

async function step() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        onlyBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            result = "nice";
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}

realMain();
```

```html
<div>
    <button id="onlyButton">Run</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `console.log` in `realMain` function. The `result` variable is still not set. The value is set when `onlyBtn` receives `click` event. So you just need to print the result in the event callback.

And assuming your snippet is your full code, the logic for `step` async function is wrong. It is not doing anything related to async, just setting up an event listener. So it should not be async at all.

Answer (score 0):

You juste need to move you resolve() call into you eventListener, look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new-tdd-u8s8xi?file=/src/index.js)